# regex для определения страны в скобках

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, работа-с-текстом

Помогите составить регулярное выражение, для определения страны в круглых скобках. Например даны строки:

1. Тонер Imex Универсальный для Samsung, Тип SML `(фасовка Германия)` Bk, 700 г, канистра
2. Дозирующее (текст который нужно оставить) лезвие `( Германия)` для HP LJ M203/M227"
3. Блок самоклеящийся LACO `(ЛАКО, Германия)`, 76х76 мм

Необходимо вырезать только следующий текст: `(ЛАКО, Германия), (фасовка Германия), ( Германия)`

Comment: Сформулируйте точный и однозначный признак, который позволяет различить "(текст который нужно оставить)" и текст, который необходимо вырезать.

Comment: Текст который необходимо вырезать заранее неизвестен. Есть справочник стран. И при наличии названии страны в строке ее нужно вырезать, со всем, что указано вместе с ней в круглых скобках

Comment: Интересно, как, по-Вашему, регулярное выражение должно работать с внешним справочником? Так что для именно заданного  вопроса (строго регэкспы) эти сведения бесполезны.

Comment: Как оно будет работать со справочником никакого отношения к вопросу не имеет. об этом я не и спрашиваю. Смысл в том, что на месте (Германия) может оказаться любое значение, которое будет компилиться в паттерне в момент определения.

Comment: Имеет, и самое прямое. Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Шаблон: `^(.+)(\([^(]*\))([^()]*)$`

Замена: `\1\3`

[RegEx fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/Mr5gdA/1)

> на месте (Германия) может оказаться любое значение, которое будет компилиться в паттерне в момент определения

Ну так добавить его в шаблон...

Шаблон: `^(.+)(\([^(]*Германия[^(]*\))([^()]*)$`

Замена: `\1\3`

[RegEx fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/Mr5gdA/3)

Answer (score 0):

В регулярке задал шаблоны поиска с скобками. При успешном нахождении удаляем:

```
String[] items = {
    "Тонер Imex Универсальный для Samsung, Тип SML (фасовка Германия) Bk, 700 г, канистра",
    "Дозирующее лезвие (Германия) для HP LJ M203/M227",
    "Блок самоклеящийся LACO (ЛАКО, Германия), 76х76 мм",
    "Блок самоклеящийся LACO (Germany), 76х76 мм",
};

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((\\w+ \\w+)\\)|\\((\\w+)\\)|\\((\\w+, \\w+)\\)", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);

for (String text : items) {
    System.out.println(text);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
        text = m.replaceAll("");
        System.out.println(text);
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Консоль:

```
Тонер Imex Универсальный для Samsung, Тип SML (фасовка Германия) Bk, 700 г, канистра
(фасовка Германия)
Тонер Imex Универсальный для Samsung, Тип SML  Bk, 700 г, канистра

Дозирующее лезвие (Германия) для HP LJ M203/M227
(Германия)
Дозирующее лезвие  для HP LJ M203/M227

Блок самоклеящийся LACO (ЛАКО, Германия), 76х76 мм
(ЛАКО, Германия)
Блок самоклеящийся LACO , 76х76 мм

Блок самоклеящийся LACO (Germany), 76х76 мм
(Germany)
Блок самоклеящийся LACO , 76х76 мм
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так:

```
private String removeCountry(String name) {
    //проход по справочнику стран
    for (String c : CountyDictionaries.countries) {
        String p = String.format("\\(.*%s\\)", c);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String founded = matcher.group();
            String toDelete = founded.substring(founded.lastIndexOf("("),
                    founded.lastIndexOf(")") + 1);
            return name.replace(toDelete, "")
                    .replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
                    .replaceAll(",{2}", "\\,");
        }
    }
    return name;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Было  : Маркер универсальный для любой гладкой поверхности со стирателем STAEDTLER (Германия), ЧЕРНЫЙ, 1 мм, 305 M-9
Станет: Маркер универсальный для любой гладкой поверхности со стирателем STAEDTLER, ЧЕРНЫЙ, 1 мм, 305 M-9
=========================================
Было  : Маркер перманентный (нестираемый) STAEDTLER (Германия) Lumocolor, КРАСНЫЙ, круглый наконечник, 0,4 мм, 313-2
Станет: Маркер перманентный (нестираемый) STAEDTLER Lumocolor, КРАСНЫЙ, круглый наконечник, 0,4 мм, 313-2
=========================================
Было  : Карандаш механический LACO (ЛАКО, Германия), корпус черный, ластик, 0,5 мм, MP 12
Станет: Карандаш механический LACO, корпус черный, ластик, 0,5 мм, MP 12
=========================================
Было  : Набор STAEDTLER (Германия), карандаши чернографитные 5 шт. (НВ), резинка стирательная, 120 A SBKD10
Станет: Набор STAEDTLER, карандаши чернографитные 5 шт. (НВ), резинка стирательная, 120 A SBKD10
```